# How to remove rectangle frame on a captured image in iPhone

Tags: swift, image, avcapture

I am new to iOS and i use avcaptuesession to capturing an image in my application.After capture an image it shows a rectangle frame on the image.

This is how I get the output.i need to remove the rectangle overlay on the image.how can i resolve this? any help would be appreciated.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use can resolve by `allowsEditing` make it false

```
var img = UIImagePickerController()
img.allowsEditing = false
```

Comment: thank you.But I am using AVcapturesssion.is it possible for that?